# Get Chrome URL using Google Developer API or Chrome Plugin

Tags: google-chrome, url, visual-c++

I am trying to get current active tab URL of the chrome browser (v.35+) in VC++ application. I could succeed to capture the URL using Windows Activity Accessibility (MSAA) but I am trying to get URL using other methods also.

I have tried by WinDDE but current Chrome version 35 doesn't support it. Using WinDDE, I could get URL from IExplore and Firefox.

Is it possible to get URL using Chrome Plugin. ( I don't know how to write it ) or Is there any way to do it.

Also do Google Development APIs have COM library for C++ application like they have GetURL in chrome.extension https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension